# Angular-UI Typeahead NoResults causes flicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an input configured with Angular-UI Typeahead.  When there are no results, a div is set to appear with some additional fields. The problem is that there is a very noticeable flicker after the div appears and user continues typing.

I've noticed that the $digest cycle runs twice for each keystroke, and that the value of NoResults property toggles from false and then back to true, which would explain the flicker. I also notice that the call stack contains "Scope.$digest.done" for the second cycle.

Is there a way I can $watch the NoResults property and identify those events that are triggered from the "done" cycle?  Or is there a better approach to solving this problem?